# Typemismatch with I18N Label instead of Attribute Name

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-validation

My message.properties contains this by default:

typeMismatch.java.lang.Double=Property {0} must be a valid number

Placeholder {0} is replaced by the Attribute Name. I want to use the Label that is used for the frontend like this:

typeMismatch.java.lang.Double=Property {wonderful label here} must be a valid number.

**My first Attempt:**

typeMismatch.java.lang.Double=Property ${message(code:'0')} must be a valid number.

is not working cause there is no '0' message. Documentation is not clear at that point.
Anyone got an idea for this one?

**Edit:**

Well i can write an error message for every Attribute like this:

typeMismatch.Book.booknumber = Property Booknumber must be a valid number.

But this seems like a lot of extra work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I made an little mistake.. it is damm easy now...I'll answer it here. Maybe someone will run into this:

**My Mistake was:**

```
typeMismatch.java.lang.Double=Property {0} must be a valid number
```

{0} was replaced by the Attributes Name.

The Reason behind that was that Grails API rendererror is looking for correct Classnames and Properties.

**For example:**

My Class is named Book and Property is number.

In my message properties:

```
book.number = Booknumber
```

For i18n everything worked fine, but when the error message has to occur it shows the following:

```
"Property number must be a valid number."
```

**Correct Version in message properties:**

```
Book.number = Booknumber
```

Works for me now. :-)

Comment: For me i needed to do this (ie end it with ".label"): 
com.my.pkg.MyDomainClass.title.label=Custom Title
com.my.pkg.MyDomainClass.label=My Custom Domain Class Title

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! Thanks so much for your post! 
When it didn't work for me at first, it took me some time to realize that I needed to use the fully qualified class name in front of the property name. So the syntax is:

```
package.ClassName.propertyName=Label
```

Very useful! Thanks again!
Al

Answer (score 0):

Spring's Data binding error validators ("{0}" must be a valid number) want `fullClassName.fieldName`
Short class name and/or .label are not recognized, see `org.springframework.validation.DefaultBindingErrorProcessor#getArgumentsForBindError`

Grails validators ("{0} must be a valid email address") want `FQClassName.fieldName.label` or `classPropertyName.fieldName.label`
Adding `.label` is a must, as evident from `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint#rejectValueWithDefaultMessage`

Hence you need both `FQN/shortClassName.attributeName.label` **and** `FQN.attributeName` to get the same translatable human-friendly name in both validations.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8369

Answer (score 0):

One other hint, in case it helps the next person, if you are getting an unfriendly error message like "Property producer.employeeCount must be a valid number" try adding a property called simply producer.employeeCount to your messages.properties file, as such:

producer.employeeCount=Number of Employees

At least in Grails 2.0.0, this will result in a friendlier message: "Property Number of Employees must be a valid number."

Using the fully qualified class name (e.g. com.example.domain.Client.employeeCount), with or without ".label" at the end did not work for me.

Hope this helps someone.